# I want to serve a Django website from a Raspberry pi, setup as an access point in a standalone network (not connected to the internet)

Tags: django, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a project to serve a django website from a raspberry pi thatis set up as an access point in a standalone network(not connected to the internet) just a minimum pi setup,am able to set it up as a wifi access point, but the challenge now is deploying the django website and serving it over the wifi access point to any connected device. am hoping somone could guid me through this orpoint me to any link with a guide to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Generally, deploying in raspberry should be same, [look here about deploying django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-django-to-app-platform). The main difference from the VPS your need to spend little time with your network. Googling about deploying django on raspberry gives a lot of results, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=deploy%20django%20raspberry%20pi&oq=deploying%20django%20ras&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30.4950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)